# What endpoint do I query for information about an Application?

Tags: api

I'm working on a mobile app for Salesforce and currently running an SOQL query to retrieve a list of Salesforce Applications accessible by the user - using this query string:

```
SELECT Id, ApplicationId, Label FROM AppMenuItem WHERE IsAccessible = TRUE AND IsVisible = TRUE ORDER BY UserSortOrder NULLS LAST, SortOrder NULLS LAST LIMIT 10
```

This correctly gives me a list of applications the user has access to. What I'd like to do now is choose one of those applications and query Salesforce for a list of pages/tabs (sorry still not up to speed on Salesforce nomenclature) so that I can then render navigation onto the screen for that application. What endpoint would I go about querying to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article might help:

- [Describing Tabs Using Schema Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeTabs.htm)

Also, you might find more information you are looking for via the `Metadata REST API` more information here:

- [Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm)

But that will require a REST API call rather than a plain `SOQL` query.